# Access denied to database in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error while creating check_login page

> Cannot select DB: Access denied for user "@'localhost' to database 'clg'.

I have created the table in phpMyAdmin.
How can I solve this?

Here's the complete code:

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="clg"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="hr"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse. 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die('cannot connect:' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die('cannot select DB:' . mysql_error());

//Define $username and $password 
$userid = $_POST['userid']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection) 
$userid = stripslashes($userid); 
$password = stripslashes($password); 
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($userid); 
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password); 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE userid='$userid' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row 
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row 
if($count==1){ 
   // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php" 
   session_register("userid"); 
   session_register("password"); 
   header("location:login_success.php"); 
} else { 
   echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
}
```

Comment: How are you attempting to connect to the database?

Comment: sry..bt i did not understand your question..can you be more specific..

Comment: He's asking to post the database connectivity code you are using

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a data base

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a php script (like any other php script) that manges mysql databases. it is one of many ways to manage a mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should grant privileges to the user, maybe using phpmyadmin.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: how should we do that?I have tried all the ways but i m not able to find how its done.

Comment: Pls post your db connectivity code

Comment: mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die('cannot connect:' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die('cannot select DB:' . mysql_error());

Comment: Have you checked the `$username`'s permission for this db?

Comment: You can try `IP` in place of `localhost` .Also try `user: "root"`, `password: ""`- these are by default

Comment: the whole table got deleted,i am fixing this problem..so please wait for a minute..i ll get to you after checking whats wrong.

Comment: $host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="clg"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="hr"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die('cannot connect:' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die('cannot select DB:' . mysql_error());

Comment: //Define $username and $password
$userid=$_POST['userid'];
$password=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$userid = stripslashes($userid);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($userid);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE userid='$userid' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

Comment: / Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("userid");
session_register("password"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

Comment: Do you think anything is understood what all you've written? Pls add code to the quesition instead with roper formatting

Comment: i have posted the whole code in 3 parts.can you just go through it

Comment: Lol, I think you are new to stackoverflow. You must go through the abouts first. Anyways, Ill edit your ques

Comment: Is username blank? If yes, write `root` instead

Comment: ya..done dat..and the felid names are id,name,password.

Comment: Is the error gone now?

Comment: yes.the error is gone bt there are more errors to solve.

Comment: should i replace all the userid's with name?

Comment: See, if this error is gone pls mark this as correct by clicking on right tick, then post a new question - this discussion is getting too long